# simple css grid not working on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I'm experimenting with css grid and i'm trying to make a simple example, but it does not seem to work on IE11 although i use the appropriate syntax:

```css
.grid {
  background: gold;
  height: 90vh;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 405px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 405px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
}

section {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section>
    section1
  </section>
  <section>
    section2
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Making CSS Grid work in IE is not trivial task. This article might help you here: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov - I actually found a way as you can see in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to explicitly set the location of each element of the grid, so for the example in the question, you'll need to do this:

```
<div class="grid">
  <section class="s1">
    section1    
  </section>
  <section class="s2">
    section2
  </section>
</div>

.s1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;

}

.s2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;

}
```

Doing it manually can be very tedious, but if you use grid-template-areas, [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) will automatically render it for you.

So the final example looks like this:

```css
.grid {
  grid-template-areas: "s1 s2";
  background: gold;
  height: 500px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 405px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 405px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
}

.grid .grid{
    height: 300px;
}

.s1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: s1;
}

.s1 .s1 {
  background: teal;
}

.s2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: s2;
}

.s2 .s2 {
  background: yellow;
}

section section {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section class="s1">
    section1    
  </section>
  <section class="s2">
    <div class="grid">
      <section class="s1">
    nested-section1    
  </section>
  <section class="s2">
    nested-section2
  </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: IE stacks all grid items to the very first grid cell. So values `-ms-grid-column: 1` and `-ms-grid-row: 1` can be omitted because they are default.

Comment: this is generated by autoprefixer